# How do I make time.getSeconds() go from 60 to 0 instead of 0 to 60

Tags: javascript

Would It be possible to make time.getSeconds(); go down instead of up?

```
var time = new Date();
var time2 = time.getSeconds();

console.log(time2)
```

Comment: `console.log(60 - time2)`?

Comment: Yes but I want the time2 to start at 0 and subtract from 60 every second basically

Comment: No, you cannot make `getSeconds()` go down instead of up. You can manipulate its output so that the logged values go down instead of up.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = new Date();
var time2 = time.getSeconds();

const output = 60 - time2;
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hey is it possible to make time.getSeconds(); start at a custom time?

Comment: No because `time.getSeconds()` actually returns the number of seconds past the current minute in real time

Comment: Like make it start at 1 second

Comment: You can't update the getSeconds, instead, you can add a new method for the Date prototype

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```js
var secondsInMinute = 60;
var time = new Date();
var time2 = secondsInMinute - time.getSeconds();

console.log(time2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could add you own function to Date prototype (called `getMySeconds`) to get seconds in reverse way like:

```js
Date.prototype.getMySeconds = function () {
  return (60 - this.getSeconds());
}

var time = new Date();
var time2 = time.getMySeconds();

console.log(time2)
```